# How do we vertically delete values from a single column?

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, document-library, list-view, modern-experience

Within a SharePoint Online list, there are options to either enter and exit out of *Grid view* to select and edit various parts of a list in a grid like fashion.

I see I can use my mouse to select, pull, and drag in order to select multiple row values from a single column.

My list example

```
Column A | Column B | Column C
value1
value2
value3
etc...
```

But, how do we bulk delete all values from a single column and still keep the column?

In my example above its, value1, value2 .... value1000.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no direct way to remove all values vertically in particular column in **Grid view**.

As a workaround, follow steps given below:

1. Click on column cell in first row.

[image]

2. Remove its value (Click **Delete** on keyboard directly or click again in cell & use "Backspace" to delete value).
3. Select the small dot at the bottom right of column cell.

[image]

4. Drag it down for all the rows where you want to remove the column value.

[image]

**Output**:

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Here is a workaround which may be easier to carry out.

1. Select all items with the toggle selection.
2. Click edit button, then you will be edit the column value in bulk.

Note: This operation also has the list view threshold. So it may not work when you have over 5k items.
[image]

Comment: This works if I want to change the value.  But I want to delete the values.