# SPO List: Select All Items: Make one choice selection for all items

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, list-view, modern-experience, choice-field

I am looking for a way to select all rows in a list and make a single choice column selection for all rows.

My list view is filtered by [Me]. I need the user to be able to make one selection for his/her rows at once.

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Grid View for this requirements, similar to: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292845/how-do-we-vertically-delete-values-from-a-single-column/292848#292848. Let me know if this works for you. Instead of blank selection in first row, you have to selection as per your requirements.

Comment: @GaneshSanap This is precisely what I needed. Feeling a little stupid that I did not know that before.  Thanks you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments above, You can use **Edit in Grid View** option in SharePoint online modern experience lists for your requirements to update a choice column value for multiple items in the list view.

Check my answer on this thread for detailed steps (with images):
[How do we vertically delete values from a single column?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292845/how-do-we-vertically-delete-values-from-a-single-column/292848#292848)

Instead of blank selection in first row, you have to select one of the options from the choice column as per your requirements and then drag the column cell all the way down.

Comment: You can also use Bulk Edit option for selected list items using Details Pane ( i ) / Information icon at the top right corner of list command bar. Check this: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/blogs/bulk-edit-properties-in-sharepoint-online-modern-experience

Comment: Two great things I've learned today!! Awesome.  Thank you!

Comment: You're welcome!

Answer (score 0):

You can use the "Quick Edit" option to select multiple rows in a list and update a single choice column for all the selected rows at once. Here's how:

1. Navigate to the list you want to update.
2. Click the "Quick Edit" button in the "List" tab of the ribbon. This will open the list in a grid view.
3. Select the rows you want to update by clicking on the checkbox next to each row.
4. Click on the cell in the choice column you want to update for all the selected rows.
5. Select the choice you want to apply to all the selected rows.
6. Click "Stop" in the "Quick Edit" tab of the ribbon to save your changes.

Note that this will update the choice column for all the selected rows, regardless of who created them.