How to mass delete/remove choice column properties for files?
I am using Sharepoint Online. I want to be able to remove a choice column property from multiple pictures in my sharepoint site. I have the photos in the same folder with multiselect on. All of the photos in the folder have the properties "Architectual" and "Structural", and I want to remove the properties in an efficient way. The only way I can delete the property is by clicking on a singular picture, clicking properties, and deleting the properties.
If I select multiple pictures, the properties tab becomes blank and I am only able to overwrite the current properties instead of remove them.
My current workaround is to make a choice in the column as "Blank" or "." to show that there is no property there.
Please let me know if there is an efficient way to do this, preferably without Power Automate.

How many files you have? Try my solution given here and let me know if it works for you: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/292845/how-do-we-vertically-delete-values-from-a-single-column/292848#292848

@GaneshSanap-MVP Thank you so much! This is what I was looking for

Great, glad it worked for you!

You can try below way to remove all values in particular column in Grid view from SharePoint list view.
Follow steps given below:

Open list view in "Edit in grid view" mode.

Click on column cell in first row.


Remove its value (Click Delete on keyboard directly or click again in cell & use "Backspace" to delete value).

Select the small dot at the bottom right of column cell.


Drag it down for all the rows where you want to remove the column value.



Output:


PowerShell is also a good method, please refer to these articles:
PowerShell Scripts to Manage Choice Field in SharePoint
SharePoint Online: Update Choices in the Choice Field using PowerShell

@GaneshSanap-MVP has the answer I was looking for. Thank you for replying
